# How to omit form's validation at AJAX button click?

Tags: ajax, forms

I have an AJAX button that should update form fields according to data already provided by user:

```
 'ajax_button' => array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t("Scan for tags"),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_tag',
      'wrapper' => 'dynamic-tags-fieldset',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'event' => 'click',
      'prevent' => 'submit click mousedown',
    ),
  ),
```

It works, but only if form is valid. Of course I do not want to validate it just yet. I don't care if all fields are filled, I only need my form to be updated at this very moment. How can I make form api **not** to invoke hook_form_validate() and not test `#required` fields?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`#limit_validation_errors`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#limit_validation_errors) property:

> Provides an array of sections which are parts of $form_state['values'] which should be validated, implying that sections which are not listed should not be validated. This is normally used in multistep forms in the case of a "back" button, for example, where '#limit_validation_errors' => array() would mean not to validate anything as form values on the current page are to be discarded anyway. #limit_validation_errors does not have any effect if #submit is not set. More discussion is in the [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) documentation.

e.g.

```
'ajax_button' => array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t("Scan for tags"),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_tag',
      'wrapper' => 'dynamic-tags-fieldset',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'event' => 'click',
      'prevent' => 'submit click mousedown',
    ),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(), // No elements will be validated
    '#submit' => array('custom_function'), // An explicit submit functions array is required for this, but may be empty
  ),
```

However, each validation function is free to respect '#limit_validation_errors' or not. If you want your validation functions to respect this parameter, you need to:

- Obtain #limit_validation_errors value from clicked button using `$form_state['clicked_button']['#limit_validation_errors']`
- Pass it as a third argument to each [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) call

Comment: Nope, not working. I added `'#limit_validation_errors' => array(), '#submit' => array(),` to my button but the validation is fired anyway. I cleared cache liberally with no result.

Comment: As I understand it `#submit` can't be empty, it needs to point to the submission handler for that button

Comment: Nope, it can be empty all right. I'll edit your answer, as you provided only half of it and I just found second half. Edit: Done. And now it works.

Comment: I've never come across that behaviour before, and according to the `form_set_error()` docs: _"Partial form validation is implemented by suppressing errors rather than by skipping the input processing and validation steps entirely"_. So while what you're saying is true, the error messages will definitely be suppressed without needing to pass anything extra to `form_set_error()`. I use `#limit_validation_errors` a lot and I've never come across that issue. Indeed that argument is for "Internal use only", per the docs so shouldn't be set by a custom form

Comment: "$limit_validation_errors: Internal use only. The #limit_validation_errors property of the clicked button, if it exists." - well, what I added should NOT be needed, according to this, but it **IS** needed now in 7.22. Do you think I should report it as a core bug at drupal.org?

Comment: I'm using 7.22 in pretty much all my sites and still haven't seen this behaviour. I highly doubt it's a core bug, maybe an incompatibility with an installed contrib/custom module? See if you can reproduce on a clean site, if so then yeah report it :)

Comment: I tested it on a site with only my module, views and views dependences enabled. It seems to happen only in connection with AJAX, though. Without AJAX it seems to work all right... http://drupal.org/node/1997190

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, that I was unable to fix with `#limit_validation_errors`. So I found a dirty hack that I want to share, but strongly advise against, unless you know what you are doing.

Caveat / disclaimer:

- I am still not fully aware myself of the consequences of this hack. I am still experimenting.
- This answer is not a complete tutorial. It is meant for people who already know all the "official" information about form API.
- There may be other, better ways to solve my specific problem. However, I still want to share this, because it provides a way to skip the entire validation + submission + rebuilding step. So even if in my case it turns out to be not necessary, for other it might be useful or interesting.
- As said: Do not try this at home!

### Use case / scenario

I was developing a custom form element type.

The element contains a button to add more items, which should change the form structure and let you continue with the modified form.

### Observations about form API

Currently, if you have a form element with a `'#process'` callback and a `'#value_callback'` callback, and you click a submit button, each of these callbacks will be called twice during the POST request.

Why is this?

Let's have a look at `drupal_process_form()`. At first, this calls `form_builder()` directly, which recursively visits all form elements and calls `#process`, `#value_callback` and other callbacks.

Then, if `$form_state['process_input']` is TRUE, it will call `drupal_validate_form()`, execute the submit handlers, and call `drupal_rebuild_form()`. The `drupal_rebuild_form()` calls `form_builder()`, which again fires all the element callbacks.

Between and during these two steps, there is logic that can mess with `$form_state['values']` and `$form_state['input']`. So, if you have very dynamic form elements, it could happen that on the second call to `#value_callback`, you have a different result than on the first such call.

Overall, it would be nice if we could just skip the entire validation + submission altogether, if there was no actual submit button clicked.

### Skip validation + submission + rebuilding?

In `drupal_process_form()`, we see this code:

```
  $form = form_builder($form_id, $form, $form_state);

  // Only process the input if we have a correct form submission.
  if ($form_state['process_input']) {
    drupal_validate_form($form_id, $form, $form_state);
```

We see that the entire validation, submission, and rebuilding is only done if `$form_state['process_input']` is true.

My first idea was to directly set `$form_state['process_input'] = FALSE;` in my custom form element's `#value_callback`. However, I noticed this has undesirable consequences, because other `form_builder()` logic depends on this being TRUE.

The trick was to set `$form_state['process_input'] = FALSE;` as the last thing that would happen before the check in `drupal_process_form()`.

The place to do this is in a callback registered into `$form_state['complete form']['#after_build']`.

### Step by step

1. In the custom element's `#process` callback, add the button:

   $element['addmore'] = [
     '#type' => 'button',
     '#name' => $element['#name'] . '[addmore]',
     '#value' => t('Add item'),
   ];

It is important that the #name of the button is set explicitly, otherwise Drupal will set `$button['#name'] = 'op'`.

Also note that this button does not have a #submit function. This is ok, because all the logic will be in the #value_callback.

Having the name on the button means that a click will be noticed in the `$input` parameter of the `#value_callback`.

2. In the `'#value_callback'` of the custom form element:

   if (isset($input['addmore'])) {
       // Button was clicked.
       $form_state['complete form']['#after_build'][] = '_MYMODULE_form_after_build_unset_process_input';
       // Add an "empty" item.
       $values[] = NULL;
     }

Note: This is not the complete `#value_callback`! It is your job to figure out the rest.

3. Write the callback function:

   function _MYMODULE_form_after_build_unset_process_input(array $form, array &$form_state) {
     $form_state['process_input'] = FALSE;
     return $form;
   }

Due to the way this function is registered, it really fires at the correct time.

4. Ajaxify.

The previous instructions give you a non-ajax version.

How to add AJAX behavior depends a lot on the use case, so I am going to omit this part.

Note: With AJAX, we can actually use `$form_state['input']['_triggering_element_name']` in the `#value_callback`, to determine which button was clicked. Note that at this time, `$form_state['triggering_element']` is not yet filled.