# "Add More" button to form

Tags: forms

I'm trying to add an "add more" field to a form in my custom module. I've been looking at the examples module, with no luck.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['names_fieldset'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('People coming to the picnic'),
  // Set up the wrapper so that AJAX will be able to replace the fieldset.
  '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

if (empty($form_state['num_names'])) {
  $form_state['num_names'] = 1;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {
  $form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
  );
}

$form['names_fieldset']['add_name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Add one more'),
  '#submit' => array('spower_add_more_add_one'),
  // See the examples in ajax_example.module for more details on the
  // properties of #ajax.
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'spower_add_more_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
  ),
);

if ($form_state['num_names'] > 1) {
  $form['names_fieldset']['remove_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Remove one'),
    '#submit' => array('spower_add_more_remove_one'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'spower_add_more_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
  );
}
```

```
function spower_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $base = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
  );

  return array(
    'spower_my_form' => $base + array(
      'template' => 'spower',
    ),
  );
}

function spower_add_more_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['names_fieldset'];
}

/**
 * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
 *
 * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
 */
function spower_add_more_add_one($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['num_names']++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

/**
 * Submit handler for the "remove one" button.
 *
 * Decrements the max counter and causes a form rebuild.
 */
function spower_add_more_remove_one($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['num_names'] > 1) {
    $form_state['num_names']--;
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

The problem is that when I click "add more", the entire form is submitted.

If the above isn't clear, I've added the module at http://pastebin.com/Hn7bkM2v and the spower_elements.inc at http://pastebin.com/CwHW5mSm.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by, "the entire form is submitted"? Do you mean the form submission handler is invoked?

Comment: Yes - the form sumission handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a well known problem of Drupal 7 - every form button is rendered with `type="submit"`.

What you need to do, is to add `prevent="click submit mousedown"` to your button, to prevent actual submission. Maybe only one of those 3 is really needed, but this combination gave me pretty consistent results.

OK, but the above only prevents form from actual saving data. It still gets validated, and that's not exactly what you want, right? I already got answer on [how to omit form's validation at AJAX button click](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/how-to-omit-forms-validation-at-ajax-button-click#answer-73384).

Other approach would be to either add custom form element, let's call it real_button, a copy of button but with `type="button"`, or to change type on document ready using jQuery.

Comment: That was the trick - thanks for the help. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: I guess it's a different problem now, but after I press the "add more" button, the ids for the text boxes change every time one is added or removed. Is there a way to keep them the same? I need to access the text boxes by id.

Comment: I figured it out - in the `for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++)` loop, I created an `$elementID` variable, then in the `$form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i]` array, I set the `'#id' => $elementID,`

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for 2 hours and I figured it out. In my case, in the place of modulename (e.g. godown) in the code snippet it actally had to be the form name (e.g. godown_item_form).

All along the way, I was replacing the modulename in the code with godown (my module's name), but when I replaced it with godown_item_form (my form's name) it started working like a charm.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's not clear to what snippet you are referring. Functions implemented from a module (especially hooks) need to be prefixed by the module name, not the form's name. While that worked for you, this is not the solution for everybody. It is rather probable there is another bug in your code, which is not the same the OP is noticing.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT** note to everyone using this with a "Number of values" setting greater than one (read: If the user can add additional copies of the entire field type via the "Add another item" button.).

For over an hour now I have been struggling trying to fix a problem: After the AJAX callback triggered, an incorrect `$delta` value was used every time during the ajax form rebuilding process. To be more precise, it always used the `$delta` value referencing to the very last item in the list, regardless of whether I pressed the button of the first, second or last item.

The ridiculously simple solution to this involves to quick steps:

1. Append the `$delta` value to the ajax wrapper.

   (This is optional really, and just to produce for correct markup, otherwise you would have multiple wrappers with the very same ID. Drupal's AJAX is still smart enough to target the correct wrapper regardless of the multiple ID copies.)

   ```
   $form['names_fieldset'] = array(
     '#type' => 'fieldset',
     '#title' => t('People coming to the picnic'),
     // Set up the wrapper so that AJAX will be able to replace the fieldset.
     '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper-'.$delta.'">',
     '#suffix' => '</div>',
   );
   ```
2. Include the `$delta` value in the `#name` element of the "add one more" ajax button.
       
   this makes sure the system can distinguish between the "add one more" button of each item.

   ```
   $form['names_fieldset']['add_name'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => t('Add one more'),
     '#name' => 'add-name-'.$delta, // <-- most important bit
     '#submit' => array('spower_add_more_add_one'),
     // See the examples in ajax_example.module for more details on the
     // properties of #ajax.
     '#ajax' => array(
       'callback' => 'spower_add_more_callback',
       'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper-'.$delta, // <-- accompany the name wrapper IDs
     ),
   );
   ```

   Additionally, if you followed step 1 above, you will also need to update the `wrapper` attribute as seen in this code.

   And obviously the same will need to be done to the "remove one" button.

Again, the most important step is adding the unique `#name` attribute for all buttons for all items. Once I have added that, everything started working flawlessly here, as the correct `$delta` value is now being used after the callback function.

Hope this helps should anyone else ever run into this problem too.