# Programmatically add more 'paragraphs' in form alter ajax call

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, paragraphs

I have a content type called **repair** that has a multi paragraph field (field_products) called **Products**.

In the create new **repair** form I have an ajax button that fetches **N** number of products and returns the $form['field_products'] for re-render.

By default the form shows only 1 *paragraph subform.*

My question is how do I programmatically show **N** number of *paragraph subforms* based on the number of products fetched. The behavior I want is the equivalent of clicking the **Add Product** *(add more)* button **N** times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Add More" button to form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73496/add-more-button-to-form). This is similar to how to do so in Drupal 8. May help you narrow down your question to something specific.